# Angular Convert API JSON Response Object with Fields to Array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, asp.net-web-api

Learning Angular and having been through the heroes tutorial I wanted to try a real world http request so I am hitting the MetOffice DataPoint API.  A JSON object is being returned that won't currently convert to an array for me to loop through.  I am getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Having researched for a while now and tried a number of different suggestions from very similar questions, the closest being [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308423/how-to-convert-json-object-to-an-typescript-array), below are the various things I have tried with comments on what failed at each attempt.  I have confirmed in JSONLint that the JSON is valid.

**Model**

```
export class Site {
  elevation: number;
  id: number;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  name: string;
  region: string;
  unitaryAuthArea: string;
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class MetOfficeService {
    private testUrl = 'http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?key=xxx';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getSites(): Observable<Site[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.testUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response){
        let body = res.json().Location;  Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
        //let body = res.json()['Location']; Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
        //let temp = res.json()['Location'];
        //let body = JSON.parse(temp); Unexpected token o on line 1 ... this is because of unrequired parsing i have discovered
        //return body || { }; this is nonsense.
        return body.data || { };
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [MetOfficeService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'test!';
  errorMessage: string;
  sites: Site[];

  ngOnInit() { this.getSites(); }

  constructor(private moService: MetOfficeService) { }
  getSites(){
      this.moService.getSites()
        .subscribe(
            sites => this.sites = sites,
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
};
```

**View**

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<div id="sites">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let site of sites">
      {{site.name}} ||| {{site.unitaryAuthArea}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As always, all help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:  A snippet of the JSON, it has 4,000 location objects or so.

```
{
    "Locations": {
        "Location": [{
            "elevation": "7.0",
            "id": "3066",
            "latitude": "57.6494",
            "longitude": "-3.5606",
            "name": "Kinloss",
            "region": "gr",
            "unitaryAuthArea": "Moray"
        }, {
            "elevation": "6.0",
            "id": "3068",
            "latitude": "57.712",
            "longitude": "-3.322",
            "obsSource": "LNDSYN",
            "name": "Lossiemouth",
            "region": "gr",
            "unitaryAuthArea": "Moray"
        }, {
            "elevation": "36.0",
            "id": "3075",
            "latitude": "58.454",
            "longitude": "-3.089",
            "obsSource": "LNDSYN",
            "name": "Wick John O Groats Airport",
            "region": "he",
            "unitaryAuthArea": "Highland"
        }]
    }
}
```

**Update** Developer Tools showing response

[image]

Comment: How *does* the JSON look like that you are receiving? (in network tab)

Comment: It seems you are just not receiving anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `res.json().Location` but `res.json().Locations` (note the "s") and furthermore, there is no object `data` that you are trying to extract from the response, but `Location`. So if you want to extract the array, your `extractData` should look like this:

```
private extractData(res: Response){
    let body = res.json().Locations.Location;  
    return body || [];
}
```

Comment: That's it.  Thank you so much for your help, I hadn't thought of "stepping" into the object like that and completely misunderstood .data

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because your extractData callback function expects a argument which is not passed

```
getSites(): Observable<Site[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.testUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData(data))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: Passing just `this.extractData` in the call is not calling the function, so there is no argument to expect. What you did in your answer is to pass _the result of the call this.extractData(data)_ into `map()` which is doubly incorrect: data is undefined and this.extractData does not return a function.