# Get array of student's id

Tags: javascript, typescript

Help me get the array of all student's id and college id from the following JSON data. 
I want to have;

```
//to store id of all colleges.
var collegeid = [];

//store id of all students.
var studentsid = [];

//students id as per college:
var studentsIdInCollege1 = [];

var data = {  
  "college":[  
    {  
      "id":1,
      "school":"abc",
      "course":"cde",
      "students":[  
        {  
          "id":1,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        },
        {  
          "id":2,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "id":2,
      "school":"xyz",
      "course":"lopl",
      "students":[  
        {  
          "id":3,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        },
        {  
          "id":4,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON object to an Typescript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308423/how-to-convert-json-object-to-an-typescript-array) - there are some other duplicates around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map()` to get college Ids:

```
let collegeIds = data.college.map(({ id }) => id);
```

Use `.reduce()` for student ids:

```
let studentIds = data.college.reduce((a, c) => (
  a.concat(c.students.map(({ id }) => id))
), []);
```

Use `.reduce()` to get an array of arrays where each array contains student ids:

```
let studentInEachCollege = data.college.reduce((a, c) => (
  a.push(c.students.map(({ id }) => id)), a
), []);
```

This will allow you to access each college students using index like `studentInEachCollege[0]` for first college, `studentInEachCollege[1]` for second and so on.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {  
  "college":[  
    {  
      "id":1,
      "school":"abc",
      "course":"cde",
      "students":[  
        {  
          "id":1,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        },
        {  
          "id":2,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "id":2,
      "school":"xyz",
      "course":"lopl",
      "students":[  
        {  
          "id":3,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        },
        {  
          "id":4,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let collegeIds = data.college.map(({ id }) => id);
let studentIds = data.college.reduce((a, c) => (
  a.concat(c.students.map(({ id }) => id))
), []);
let studentInEachCollege = data.college.reduce((a, c) => (
  a.push(c.students.map(({ id }) => id)), a
), []);

console.log(collegeIds);
console.log(studentIds);
console.log(studentInEachCollege);
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 2):

For the colleges, just `map` the college array to the `id` of each object. For the students, use `[].concat(...` to spread over a map of the student IDs and get a flat object:

```js
const input = {  
  "college":[  
    {  
      "id":1,
      "school":"abc",
      "course":"cde",
      "students":[  
        {  
          "id":1,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        },
        {  
          "id":2,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "id":2,
      "school":"xyz",
      "course":"lopl",
      "students":[  
        {  
          "id":3,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        },
        {  
          "id":4,
          "name":"abc 123",
          "number":"156888"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const collegeIds = input.college.map(({ id }) => id);
console.log('collegeIds: ' + collegeIds);
const studentIds = [].concat(...input.college.map(({ students }) => students.map(({ id }) => id)));
console.log('studentIds: ' + studentIds);
```

Comment: Thanks!. How can i get students id only for specific college. say college with id of 1.

Comment: You would select the appropriate college using `.find` and then use the same sort of `map` technique as with collegeIds over the students to get their ids.

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, i love your code , i dont understant this [].concat(...input.college.map(({ students }), three dots in concat

Comment: Am having difficulty in putting the ids in array, as;
collegeIds: [1,2] 

I tried `collegeIds[]=collegeIds.push(input.college.map(({ id }) => id));`

Comment: @7guyo Don't put empty square brackets after variable names - it's invalid syntax. Do ``const college = input.college.find(({ id }) => id === 1); const studentIds = college.students.map(({ id }) => id);``

Comment: @whoami Spread operator. It's a quick way of flat-mapping one level deep.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// College ids 
var cID = data.college.map((c) => { return c.id});

// Students
// It returns two arrays so you need to reduce it...
var students = data.college.map((c) => { return c.students});

var allStudents = students.reduce((a,b) => {return a.concat(b)}, []);

// IDs
var sID = allStudents.map((c) => { return c.id});
```