# How to convert JSON object to an Typescript array in an api

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular-cli

I'm having an API request which returns the following:

```
{
    "FarmerDetails": [
   {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  }
]
}
```

I need to show the title when I click the button and when the button clicks this "fetchPeople()" function gets call.

```
fetchPeople() {
    this.peopleService.fetchPeople().subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.people$ = res;
    });
  }
```

How can I convert my Object to Array in typescript and show particular or all values.

Comment: This might help for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308423/how-to-convert-json-object-to-an-typescript-array

Comment: @Mitesh jadav, yes I tried that too and am using angular 8

Comment: Did you try console.log(res.FarmerDetails);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling an API response object is no different to handling any other JSON object. Just query it in the same way.

Given a response like this:

```
{
  "FarmerDetails": [
    // array of objects you want to extract from the response
  ]
}
```

You can try several approaches.

1. Query the JSON object directly

```js
fetchPeople() {
  this.peopleService.fetchPeople().subscribe((res:any)=>{
    this.people = res.FarmerDetails;
  });
}
```

2. Map in the pipe

```js
fetchPeople() {
  this.peopleService.fetchPeople().pipe(
    .map(res => res.FarmerDetails)
  ).subscribe(people => {
    this.people = people;
  });
}
```

When the people service emits a value that looks like the JSON above, it applies the transform in the `map` function before returning it to the subscriber.

3. Pluck in the pipe

```js
fetchPeople() {
  this.peopleService.fetchPeople().pipe(
    .pluck('FarmerDetails')
  ).subscribe(people => {
    this.people = people;
  });
}
```

Similar to map, when the people service emits a value that looks like the JSON above, it returns the named property in the `pluck` function before returning it to the subscriber.

Approaches 2 and 3 would be preferable, as you can apply these in you service. Assuming that these come from an HTTP request, you can use the pipe after the get:

```js
export class PeopleService {
  fetchPeople() {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      pluck('FarmerDetails')
    );
  }
}
```

Also, the "$" suffix on variables is generally used to denote an observable. In your example, you're just storing the value that is emitted by the observable, so it would be confusing to name it `people$`. I have named it `people` for this reason.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time @Kurt Hamilton, In postman am using POST request for the URL " http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo" and in my service file am using the code `headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'bearer uRf0e8upueR4qTh....', 'InstanceName': 'ORISSA' , 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  fetchPeople() { return this.http.post('http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo', { headers: this.headers }); };` so am trying to pull data from this API and the result as above, If I updated the code getting response as "POST http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo 401 (Unauthorized)"

Comment: Can you please add all relevant code to your question. You asked about how to get a value from a response, but it sounds like you have an entirely different problem.

Comment: My stackblitz code url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pg6wqe, in this if i pass my api "http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo" instead of "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos" in people.service.ts it is not working. as in the sample api the json response is json array and my response is json object with array, so am trying to convert json object to array to get the response. hope this clear...

Comment: I have forked your example, and am returning an object in your structure using `of` instead of an http request for demo purposes. Here I demonstrate the use of `map` and `pluck`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkuusq

Comment: I have updated my stackblitz to make a real http request, getting the data as you described it

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kurt Hamilton for your workings, in your people.service.ts , please let me know where to update my headers where it contains authorization token, instance name, which is needed to get the datas. My header code is `headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'bearer uRf0e8upueR4qTh...','InstanceName': 'ORISSA' , 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  fetchPeople() { return this.http.post('http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo', { headers: this.headers }); };

Comment: As I said before, that sounds like a different problem that you need to research. Has my answer and demo answered your original question as it was asked?

Comment: Yes, your code is perfect...Thanks for your valuable time and I need to check the answer for why am getting unauthorised error

Comment: Great. Well please accept and upvote if that is the case. And then find out about how to add headers to a POST request. It is a heavily documented subject.

Comment: Thanks @Kurt Hamilton, how to pass values from index.js file to service.ts file in the header section.`data = response.body;console.log(data);`, my response token is stored in data, i need to pass this value in header section next to bearer in people.service.ts file ` headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
     'Authorization': 'bearer', 
     'InstanceName': 'ORISSA' , . can you please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

When you get response from api, it will return in string format. So, you require to convert it to json format. Parse it to json:

```
this.people=JSON.parse(res);
```

Comment: Are you able to log this.people? Are you getting response?

Comment: In console am getting "POST http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo 401 (Unauthorized).

Comment: Then, that is totally different to your question. It's not returning the response and how can you even convert json object to array? According to the error, you are unauthorized. May be, you require some credentials.